# Command arguments not running the rest of my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a `warn` command and my `args` aren't working and I have no idea why

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ + /g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === "warn"){
        if(message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")){
            if(!args[1]) return message.reply("Invalid Syntax: " + prefix + "warn <user> <reason>");
                console.log("this code should be run") //Nothing works here and below
                let userWarn = message.mentions.first();
                if(!userWarn) return message.reply("User not found!");
                let Warnreason = args.join(" ").slice(22);

                let warnEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
                    .setColor("#FFC300")
                    .addField("Warned user: ", userWarn)
                    .addField("Reason: " + Warnreason)

                message.channel.send(warnEmbed);
                }
             }
    })
```

Works if there are no args but when there are args it doesn't work [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Vfq.png). Also I'm getting no errors.

Comment: Assuming args is `['<@123>', 'reason']` where `123` is the ID of a user, you should be using `if (!args[1])` as arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: Tried doing that and still isn't working no errors either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot your command only has 2 arguments and `Arrays` start from `0` therefore, you should have the first argument as `args[0]` and the second argument as `args[1]`.

You also need to change `message.mentions.first()` to `message.mentions.users.first()`

Comment: Oops I just tested that and still the same result though, I'm not getting any errors eiter

Comment: can you show your `message` event from your main file?

Comment: client.on("message", message => {

    if(message.author.bot) return;

Comment: Is that all you have in your `message` event?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I posted the other part up top...

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ + /g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

Comment: and is `args` passed through your command's `run` function in `message` event?

Comment: Please respond asap :)

Comment: I'm unsure as to why you didn't receive an error about this but you wrote `message.mentions.first();` instead of `message.mentions.members.first();` which is wrong, change it and test it